# .jar file not found when building a Docker container with Palantir Gradle plug-in

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot, gradle

If I try to build a Docker container with a Spring Boot application under Windows 10, I get the following error:

```
> Task :docker FAILED
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder711841135/myproject.jar: no such file or directory
```

I'm using Docker Community Edition in version 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762) and Gradle 4.7 with Java 8.

**build.gradle** (shortened):

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.0.1.RELEASE'
    id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.19.2"
}

version = '2.0.0'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
group = "com.example"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

bootJar {
    archiveName 'myproject.jar'
}

dependencies {
    ...
}

docker {
    dependsOn(build)
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}"
    files bootJar
}
```

**Dockerfile** (sibling of build.gradle in the top-level project directory):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
COPY build/libs/myproject.jar myproject.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/myproject.jar"]
```

If I build the Docker container with Docker only (without Gradle) it works.

How can I let Gradle (or Docker?) find the file myproject.jar?

Comment: did you try `COPY build/libs/myproject.jar / `  ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes, I tried that, too, but the error is the same. There seems to be a problem with the source directory.

Comment: is there a file  build/libs/myproject.jar on the server ?

Comment: The file exists in the structure of the Gradle project. What do you mean with "on the server"? I'm running Docker locally on my development machine as a Windows service. Do I have something to do to commit the file to docker?

Comment: The file is here: `C:\Users\me\projects\myproject\trunk\Java\myproject\build\libs\myproject.jar` and I'm starting Gradle from `C:\Users\me\projects\myproject\trunk\Java\myproject`.

Comment: try it :D ```ADD build/libs/yourproject.jar /yourproject.jar```

Comment: It's the same with `ADD`.

Comment: I would just do a `COPY . /tmp` and then next line do `RUN tree /tmp` and see what is coming in context of the build

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is the `COPY` command in the Docker file:

```
COPY build/libs/myproject.jar myproject.jar
```

The source directory `build/libs/` is not where the files for building the Docker container reside. Instead the directory `build/docker/` is used as Docker build context. When `COPY` is executed this directory is the effective working directory.

The correct `COPY` command is as simple as this:

```
COPY myproject.jar /
```

Docker task:

```
docker {
    dependsOn bootJar
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}:${version}"
    files bootJar.archivePath
}
```

If you want to copy resources too, you need to add `processResources` to the `files` parameter:

```
files bootJar.archivePath, processResources
```

Comment: Nice catch, more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 8):

It works with following config of the `docker` task:

```
docker {
    dependsOn build
    name "${project.group}/${jar.baseName}"
    files bootJar.archivePath
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${bootJar.archiveName}"])
}
```

Using this slightly different docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 4):

That seems consistent with [palantir/gradle-docker issue 76](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker/issues/76) which specifies:

> I configured a new project according to examples, what I observe is that entire project **(minus `build/`)** is copied to `build/docker`. I causes an unnecessary large docker build context.

Either the `COPY` should be `build/docker/libs/myproject.jar`, or `build/` itself is not included at all.

The issue mentioned a possible workaround overriding another docker step - `dockerPrepare` - preparing the '`build/docker`' folder explicitly.

> I need only a single fatJar in addition to the Dockerfile:

```
task dockerCopy(type: MoveTo, dependsOn: dockerPrepare) {
    from('build/packed') {
        include "${jarFullName}"
    }
    into 'build/docker'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However `MoveTo` cannot be found in my case: "Could not get unknown property 'MoveTo' for root project". But it looks like the issue can be fixed with a different config of the `docker` task. I'll publish my solution here.

Answer (score 2):

What is your gradle "destinationDir" ?

The generated jar will be in destinationDir/archiveName. Perhaps target/myproject.jar

So you should put :

```
COPY target/myproject.jar myproject.jar
```

If it doesn't work, add in your gradle :

```
destinationDir target
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with `COPY build/libs/myproject.jar myproject.jar` and with setting `destinationDir` explicitly in the `bootJar` task (`destinationDir file('target')`) and `COPY target/myproject.jar myproject.jar`, but all I get is a slightly different path in the error message: `COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder548809975/target/myproject.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the similar issue. This is my [working solution](https://github.com/ashishlahoti/springboot-microservices) after spending a lot of time:-

###### build.gradle

```
String imageName = "${project.group}/${project.name}"
docker {
    //dependsOn build
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
    name imageName
    files bootJar.archiveFile.get()
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "${bootJar.archiveFileName.get()}"])
}
dockerRun {
    name "${project.name}-container"
    image imageName
    ports '8081:8081'
    env 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE': 'dev'
    daemonize true
    clean false
}
```

###### Jenkinsfile

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre

ARG APP_NAME="product-service"
ARG APP_VERSION="0.0.1"
ARG JAR_FILE="/build/libs/${APP_NAME}-${APP_VERSION}.jar"

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "app.jar"]
```

This works with Gradle tasks `:docker` and `:dockerRun`. It also works with docker command line.