# docker image of spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, amazon-ec2, microservices

I want to learn how to create docker image of spring boot application with Gradle as their is requirement for same in my shop.

To get started i have referred https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/

I followed all steps as mentioned here.

My Dockerfile look like below

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG DEPENDENCY=target/dependency
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","hello.Application"]
```

and my build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE")
           }
      }

group = 'springio'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'com.palantir.docker'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-spring-boot-docker'
   version =  '0.1.0'
      } 

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
    }

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
      compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
     testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
 }

task unpack(type: Copy) {
    dependsOn bootJar
    from(zipTree(tasks.bootJar.outputs.files.singleFile))
   into("build/dependency")
     }
docker {
    name "${project.group}/${bootJar.baseName}"
    copySpec.from(tasks.unpack.outputs).into("dependency")
    buildArgs(['DEPENDENCY': "dependency"])
 }
```

But when i am ruining

```
    $./gradlew build docker
```

Getting below error

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
       Build file '/root/springboot-Dockerf/gs-spring-boot-docker/initial/build.gradle' line: 16

    * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'initial'.
    > Plugin with id 'com.palantir.docker' not found.

    * Try:
      Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
      more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use below way

```
    plugins {
      id "com.palantir.docker" version "0.22.1"
    }

    apply plugin: "com.palantir.git-version"

    https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.palantir.docker
```

try to follow this link
    [.jar file not found when building a Docker container with Palantir Gradle plug-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941955/jar-file-not-found-when-building-a-docker-container-with-palantir-gradle-plug-i)

Comment: I tried but it failed                                                                                                          
  > startup failed:
  build file '/root/springboot-Dockerf/gs-spring-boot-docker/initial/build.gradle': 16: only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed
  
  See https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block for information on the plugins {} block
 @ line 16, column 5.
         plugins {

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49941955/jar-file-not-found-when-building-a-docker-container-with-palantir-gradle-plug-i

Comment: I have gone through these links and did some changes and now i am getting below error                                                                                                                
        * What went wrong:
           Execution failed for task ':docker'.
       > Process 'command 'docker'' finished with non-zero exit value 125